# Ruby test for line-by-line comparison

Tags: ruby, minitest

Is there a tester for minitest that does extended string comparison?
I've got large strings to compare, and if you have an error message
"they're not equal" and have to compare 20 lines each, it's not very effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

built-in functionality of minitest.